# How to write all javascript in a single file?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a website which is around 30pages total. Within all the pages there are JavaScript functionalities such as such as carousel, slider, tooltips.....

My questions are, I'm using a single Javascript file to store all the functions but since not all the functionalities are present in the page how do I trigger the JavaScript base on certain pages only and not all of them and also to avoid JavaScript error since certain elements are not present?

Comment: Check whether they're present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what libraries like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) is for. You need to organize your scripts into a number of files that are functionally similar. Use require to load the ones you need on the appropriate page.So rather than one big file load only the ones that are applicable.

Comment: Thanks appreciate that